# Struggling to deploy Ionic Web App to server

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic and have made my first app that runs perfectly locally using `ionic serve` , but I am having troubles running it on my web server.

I have read the docs and various other sources that seem to imply that you just run a `ionic build --prod` and then copy the `www` folder to your web server and away you go but I just got a white screen and no errors.

I then tried adding cordova platform browser and building using `ionic cordova build browser` and hosting the built files from this, but same result.. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Hi you can use https://stackblitz.com/ to run ionic or angular-apps direct form a git-archive, so it is easier to test !

Comment: I appreciate this but I would really like to learn the real cause of the problem so I do not have any issues when pushing to production for the client. But thank you for the help & I will be sure to check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this the other day. First off, be sure you aren't relying on any Cordova plugins as they won't work in the browser.

You do this:

1. `ionic cordova platform add browser`
2. `ionic build --prod`
3. then copy the www in `platforms\browser\www` to the webserver

This is just a basic deploy. There are tutorials for making the app a PWA (which means it can be installed via the browser as an app on your device home screen).

Comment: Thank you for the input, I found the problem I was having was because Modpagespeed was enabled on my server and this was causing the app not to load correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Deploy with NodeJs
To create the file server.js in you project directory root

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/www/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`RUNNING ON PORT ${port}`);
```

and runing command ionic build --prod && node server.js